# How to control Google Analytics tracking in Nuxt based on consent cookies?

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, nuxt.js

I implemented Google Analytics tracking using [@nuxtjs/google-analytics](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/google-analytics)

I would now like to control whether or not the user is being tracked based on a consent given by the user. I found [nuxt-cookie-control](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-cookie-control), which appears to allow collecting consent.

Based on the [documentation](https://matteogabriele.gitbooks.io/vue-analytics/content/docs/opt-out.html) for @nuxtjs/google-analytics // vue-analytics, it seems to just be a matter of calling `this.$ga.disable()` if a user does not give consent.

I noticed in some early fiddling efforts, however, that whenever I made a call to `this.$ga.disable()`, it did not seem to take effect beyond the next refresh.

The documentation also points out that "the opt-out needs to happen before trackers or queues are initialized."

I am a bit at a loss how/where in the application I would need to make the call to `this.$ga.disable()`. Can anyone give me pointers?

Comment: Did you find any pointers?

Comment: No. Switched to funneling everything through GTM using https://github.com/nuxt-community/gtm-module.

Answer (score 3):

here is my solution:

first of all i disabled google-analytics by defaut, so that no tracking takes place until the user has consented. i did this by setting the option `disabled=true` in `nuxt.config.js`. e.g.:

```js
    googleAnalytics: {
        id: 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x',
        disabled: true,
    },
```

then i configured the `accepted()` callback in the cookies config in `nuxt.config.js` to enable google analytics, if consent is done:

```js
        optional: [
            {
                name: 'Google Analytics',
                identifier: 'ga',
                description: '...',
                initialState: false,
                cookies: ['_ga', '_gat', '_gid'],
                accepted: () => {
                    window.$nuxt.$ga.enable() // Activate module
                    window.$nuxt.$ga.page(window.$nuxt.$route.path) // Track current route
                },
                declined: () => {
                    window.$nuxt.$cookies.remove('ga') // Remove any existing Google Analytics cookies
                },
            },
        ],
```

Finally we still need to enable google analytics on every following page refresh. I did this in the `mount` function of the default layout `/layouts/default.vue`:

```js
import { onAnalyticsReady } from 'vue-analytics'

export default {
    mounted() {
        onAnalyticsReady().then(() => {
            const hasConsent = this.$cookies.isEnabled('ga')
            if (hasConsent) {
                this.$ga.enable() // Activate module
                this.$ga.page(this.$route.path) // Track current route
            }
        })
    },
}
</script>
```